# Show appropriate message in upload time

Tags: asp.net, upload, updates

I have an asp.net website. Whenever I want to update website I remove all old pages and then I upload new files.

In this period of time all visitors get is exceptions. What is best way to show appropriate message like this?

"We are updating site, please visit later"

Comment: You'll need to do it in IIS I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a file called `App_Offline.htm` and add it to the root directory of the web application when you want to show a message. In that html-file you can add your custom message. Then when you are finished, just remove it or rename it.

> When ASP.NET sees this file, it will shut-down the app-domain for the application (and not restart it for requests) and instead send back the contents of the app_offline.htm.

Read more about it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You have to put `App_Offline.htm` that is called a `Holding Page` in the root directory of your web application and inside that you can write whatever you want.

ASP.NET applications will be automatically taken down when a file named `app_offline.htm` is added to the root folder of the application.

And Remove or rename to some other name that file when the site is ready to go back up

Comment: Thank you for reply. In which situation visitor see App_Offline.htm?

Comment: Whenever this file is there in the root directory of your web application..as and when you want to remove that just rename it to some other name and that's it...@masoudkeshavarz

Answer (score 0):

You can then add a
app_offline.htm
file to the root.